# PYTHONPATH environment variable...how do I make every subdirectory afterwards?

Tags: linux, unix, python, environment-variables

I currently do this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/$USER:/home/$USER/respository:/home/$USER/repository/python-stuff
```

How can I make it so that the PYTHONPATH can include everything subdirectory?

```
PYTHONPATH = /home/$USER/....and-all-subdirectories
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not how PYTHONPATH works; PYTHONPATH treats its search path differently from shell PATH.  Let's say I do this:

```
$ mkdir /home/jsmith/python
$ cd /home/jsmith/python
$ touch a.py b.py
```

This will work, in Python (`sys.path` will include the current directory):

```
$ cd /
$ PYTHONPATH=/home/jsmith/python python2.6

Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51)
>>> import a, b   # Works
>>> quit()
```

However, subdirectories are treated as packages when `__init__.py` is present in the directory, and are **ignored** by PYTHONPATH otherwise:

```
$ mkdir /home/jsmith/python/pkg
$ cd /home/jsmith/python/pkg
$ touch __init__.py c.py d.py
$ cd /
$ PYTHONPATH=/home/jsmith/python python2.6

Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51)
>>> import a, b   # Works
>>> import c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named c
```

To get at something in that subdirectory, this would work:

```
>>> from pkg import c   # Works
>>> import pkg.c        # Works
```

To roll a solution where every subdirectory in your PYTHONPATH is added, you need to explicitly add every folder to PYTHONPATH or `sys.path` programmatically.  This behavior is intentional, and behaves *nothing* like shell PATH.  Given the interpreter's support for packages in this regard, surely there's a better way to accomplish what you're after?

- [Understanding imports and PYTHONPATH](http://www.stereoplex.com/two-voices/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath)

Comment: Man, I wish each site would check your other accounts before denying you posting privileges.  It sucks starting over with rep, especially with things like the one-URL limit...(I had more references for you, OP)

Comment: I thought it was no longer necessary to add empty init.py files with namespace packages now? For python3 that is.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how environment PATH variables work - you give it the top-level directory and it's up to the application to recurse the directory tree if it needs to.

Comment: So, if I have a python file under /home/$USER/myfile.py 

Can I import this?

Comment: Sure, why couldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add subdirectories of a directory to your PYTHONPATH variable using the shell, of course.  I currently use something similar to the following in my .bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$(find $HOME/ -maxdepth 2 -type d | sed '/\/\./d' | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$//')"
```

This would include all subdirectories of your user folder to a depth of 2 in the tree.  The find command locates the directories ('-type d'), and the following sed and tr commands format the output in the usual way of PATH variables.

Leaving off '-maxdepth 2' would include all subdirectories of your home folder, which is probably quite a lot to search.  Perhaps this should only be done in your $HOME/repository/python-stuff directory.